# Need help to Format Big Number with condition in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Change the numbers format of millions in 2 digits, if the number is less than 1 Million, it should show as 0.95 - How to format number with this condition in Excel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please add a few numbers (big, small, zero, negative) and show how you would like them  represented.

Comment: You can try this custom format `#.##0..,##`

Comment: Try using this custom format: `0.00,,` using `#` hides zeros, while using `0` it won't